# Code not getting solved by NMaximize as 1/0 is encountred

Tags: mathematical-optimization, stochastic-calculus, maximize

I have the following code. This code requires to solve the model with two variables to optimize the function. a1 and a2 are the variables as shown in the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
C1 = 100;
C2 = 150;
P = 500;
M = 10000;
n1 = 140*(1 - Exp[-0.1*a1]);
n2 = 40*(1 - Exp[-0.1*a2]);
B1 = 2500;
B2 = 4500;
pdf1[a1_, x1_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n1*a1, Sqrt[n1]*2], x1];
pdf2[a2_, x2_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[n2*a2, Sqrt[n2]*2], x2];
jdf[a1_, x1_, a2_, x2_] = 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[{n1*a1, n2*a2}, {Sqrt[n1]*2, Sqrt[n2]*2}, 
    0], {x1, x2}];
assume = 
  Simplify[
   And @@ (DistributionParameterAssumptions /@ {NormalDistribution[
        n1*a1, Sqrt[n1]*2], NormalDistribution[n2*a2, Sqrt[n2]*2], 
       BinormalDistribution[{n1*a1, n2*a2}, {Sqrt[n1]*2, Sqrt[n2]*2}, 
        0]}), Element[{a1, a2}, Reals]];
t[1] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[1] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0, 
      Integrate[((-C1)*x1)*pdf1[a1, x1], {x1, 0, n1*a1}]];][[1]]
t[2] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[2] = 
     Assuming[a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[((-C1)*x2)*pdf2[a2, x2], {x2, 0, n2*a2}]];][[1]]
t[3] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[3] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C1*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x1, n1*a1, M}, {x2, 0, n2*a2}]];][[1]]
t[4] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[4] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[(P*(x1 - n1*a1) - C2*(x1))*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x1, 
        M, Infinity}, {x2, 0, n2*a2}]];][[1]]
t[5] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[5] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C1*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, n2*a2, M}, {x1, 0, n1*a1}]];][[1]]
t[6] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[6] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[(P*(x2 - n2*a2) - C2*(x2))*jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, 
        M, Infinity}, {x1, 0, n1*a1}]];][[1]]

t[7] = AbsoluteTiming[
   int[7] = 
     Assuming[a1 > 0 && a2 > 0, 
      Integrate[(P*((x2 - n2*a2) + (x1 - n1*a1)) - C2*(x1 + x2))*
        jdf[a1, x1, a2, x2], {x2, M, Infinity}, {x1, M, 
        Infinity}]];][[1]]
jexpt[a1_, a2_] = B1*n1 + B2*n2 + Total[int /@ Range[7]];
LeafCount@jexpt[a1, a2]
NMaximize[{jexpt[a1, a2], a1 > 0 && a2 > 0}, {a1, a2}, 
 MaxIterations -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 20, Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

I have taken all the timing parameters to check how the total time changes.
This shows that the infinite expression (1/0) is encountered and does not solve the problem. Can anyone fix it?

Comment: After changing both cases of `0.1` to `1/10` I do not get an error. The approximate result is `{230628., {a1 -> 9.44239, a2 -> 14.1381}}`

Comment: What changes have you made? can you show that in the answer section in the code? Are you referring to the  n1 = 140*(1 - Exp[-0.1*a1]) part?

Comment: What version are you using and which OS?

Comment: Yes, in the definitions of `n1` and `n2`. Version 13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)

Comment: the defined "assume" is not being used here in any of the calculations. Can we add that to the constraints?

Comment: The `assume` was calculated to justify using `{a1 > 0, a2 > 0}` in all subsequent calculations. Once you conclude that it is equivalent to `{a1 > 0, a2 > 0}` there is no benefit to using it further.

Comment: For the plotting, the font style is not working. I have done the following Off[General::munfl]

General::munfl


Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 5000}, 
 Show[Plot3D[Evaluate@jexpt[a1, a2], {a1, 0, 20}, {a2, 0, 20}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.8], WorkingPrecision -> 30,
    MaxRecursion -> 5], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
    Point[{a1, a2, max} /. arg]}], Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"a1", "a2", "Expected Profit"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", 12, GrayLevel[5]}]]

Comment: Do not ask new questions in comments. The original question has nothing to do with plotting or plot options. However, the documentation clearly states that "The gray level must be a number between 0 and 1." Fix that.